# How to choose bins in matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Can someone explain to me what "bins" in histogram are (the [matplotlib hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) function)? And assuming I need to plot the probability density function of some data, how do the bins I choose influence that? and how do I choose them? (I already read about them in the [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) and the [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) libraries but I did not get the idea)

Answer (score 85):

The `bins` parameter tells you the number of bins that your data will be divided into. You can specify it as an integer or as a list of bin edges.

For example, here we ask for 20 bins:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(1000)
plt.hist(x, bins=20)
```

[image]

And here we ask for bin edges at the locations [-4, -3, -2... 3, 4].

```
plt.hist(x, bins=range(-4, 5))
```

[image]

Your question about how to choose the "best" number of bins is an interesting one, and there's actually a fairly vast literature on the subject. There are some commonly-used rules-of-thumb that have been proposed (e.g. the [Freedman-Diaconis Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule), [Sturges' Rule, Scott's Rule, the Square-root rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Number_of_bins_and_width), etc.) each of which has its own strengths and weaknesses.

If you want a nice Python implementation of a variety of these auto-tuning histogram rules, you might check out the histogram functionality in the latest version of the AstroPy package, [described here](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/visualization/histogram.html).
This works just like `plt.hist`, but lets you use syntax like, e.g. `hist(x, bins='freedman')` for choosing bins via the Freedman-Diaconis rule mentioned above.

My personal favorite is "Bayesian Blocks" (`bins="blocks"`),  which solves for optimal binning with *unequal* bin widths. You can read a bit more on that [here](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/visualization/histogram.html#bayesian-models).

---

Edit, April 2017: with matplotlib version 2.0 or later and numpy version 1.11 or later, you can now specify automatically-determined bins directly in matplotlib, by specifying, e.g. `bins='auto'`. This uses the maximum of the Sturges and Freedman-Diaconis bin choice. You can read more about the options in the [`numpy.histogram` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Comment: Thank you so much! My data is about some 100 thousands of points and I need to draw a probability density function of it. Because my data has a lot of small numbers I used this:

bin_size = 0.1; min_edge = -5.; max_edge = 5.
N = (max_edge-min_edge)/bin_size; Nplus1 = N + 1
bins = np.linspace(min_edge, max_edge, Nplus1)

Comment: Would be actually great to have automatic unequal binning also in Matplotlib or NumPy or SciPy or Pandas or one of the other standard data science packages.

Answer (score 10):

To complemented [jakes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33459231/974555), you can use
[`numpy.histogram_bin_edges`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html#numpy.histogram_bin_edges) if you just want to calculate the optimal bin edges, without actually doing the histogram.  `histogram_bin_edges` is a function specifically designed for the optimal calculation of bin edges.  You can choose seven different algorithms for the optimisation.

Answer (score 6):

Bins are the number of intervals you want to divide all of your data into, such that it can be displayed as bars on a histogram. A simple method to work our how many bins are suitable is to take the square root of the total number of values in your distribution.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct in expecting that the number of bins has significant impact on approximating the true underlying distribution. I haven't read the original paper myself, but according to [Scott 1979](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/66/3/605/232642), a good rule of thumb is to use:

> *R(n^(1/3))/(3.49σ)*

where

- *R* is the range of data (in your case *R = 3-(-3)= 6*),
- *n* is the number of samples,
- σ is your standard deviation.