# Iterative binned histogramming of a 2D varaible

Tags: python, oop

So basically I was asked to design and implement a small class for iterative binned histogramming of a 2D variable (x,y), i.e. histogramming where you only have one event/fill value at a time. This should store counts of the number of (x,y) "fills" to fall into 2D intervals (x..x+dx, y..y+dy). I have no clue what this means, could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This seems like it is a request to explain histograms and binning as general concepts. stack overflow is meant for specific programming questions. Please consider making your question more specific and code related.

Comment: Also, here is a question relating to selecting bins for a histogram using `numpy` and `matplotlib`. Maybe all the links in the answers can be a good starting point for your research: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458566/how-to-choose-bins-in-matplotlib-histogram/33459231