# Putting several plots side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 9 histograms made with matplotlib.pyplot.

Is there an easy way to "stick" them to each other, so that every new histogram would not start with a new row?

Data: [data](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database/data)

Providing code:

```
for column in data:
   plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

   a1 = data[(data['Outcome'] == 0)][column]
   a2 = data[(data['Outcome'] == 1)][column]

   ax = np.linspace(0, data[column].max(), 50)

   plt.hist(a1, ax, color='blue', alpha=0.6, label='Have Diabetes = NO')
   plt.hist(a2, ax, color='yellow', alpha=0.6, label='Have Diabetes = YES')

   plt.title(f'Histogram for {column}')
   plt.xlabel(f'{column}')
   plt.ylabel('number of people')

   plt.grid(True)
   leg = plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=True)
```

What I want is something like this:

[image]

I actually don't need it to be 3x3, just not go in a column. Is it possible? Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: This is extremely poorly asked question without any code, any data, any info on how this figure is generated. You can of course use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 9)` to get 1 row and 9 columns but how you want to use that is only up to you since we don't have your data and code

Comment: Added code, however, my question is about all plots, not this specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the plots to ax , and also it will be set_title etc:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv("datasets_228_482_diabetes.csv")

fig,ax = plt.subplots(3,3,figsize=(9,9))
ax = ax.flatten()

for i,column in enumerate(data.columns):
    a1 = data[(data['Outcome'] == 0)][column]
    a2 = data[(data['Outcome'] == 1)][column]

    ax[i].hist(a1, color='blue', alpha=0.6, label='Have Diabetes = NO')
    ax[i].hist(a2, color='yellow', alpha=0.6, label='Have Diabetes = YES')

    ax[i].set_title('Histogram for '+column)
    ax[i].set_xlabel(f'{column}')
    ax[i].set_ylabel('number of people')

    ax[i].legend(loc='upper right',frameon=True,markerscale=7,fontsize=7)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

As you can see, the last column outcome is pretty useless, so if you don't plot that, you can also consider using seaborn:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=data.melt(id_vars="Outcome"),
                  col="variable",hue="Outcome",sharex=False,sharey=False,
                  col_wrap=4,palette=['blue','yellow'])
g = g.map(plt.hist,"value",alpha=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add something like 'num' in linspace to subplots?

Comment: sorry what is num ?

Comment: "num: int, optional - Number of samples to generate. Default is 50. Must be non-negative". So, in linspace I put num=50, so that my histograms look close to the picture. So, as you can see my columns are much thinner. Cannot find how to change it while using subplots.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458566/how-to-choose-bins-in-matplotlib-histogram, just increase the bins. I think if you try that e.g ax[i].hist(a1,..bins=..) it should work

Comment: I am afraid that is something not related to this question, if you still have issues with that, please post it as an question.

Comment: Yeah, it's about bins. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be plotting using `axes` rather than `pyplot`:

```
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(9,9))

 for d, ax in zip(data_list, axes.ravel()):
      ax.hist(d)   # or something similar
```