# What is nbins in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I couldn't find this in the documents. The [plotly Graphing Libraries](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/) have the below example but didn't seem to explain its arguments.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", nbins=20)
fig.show()
```

produced the plot below:
[image]

From the plot, it doesn't look like the number of bins. Neither does it reflect the bin value interval nor counts in each bin. What does `nbins=20` mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose bins in matplotlib histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458566/how-to-choose-bins-in-matplotlib-histogram)

Comment: Hi @yudhiesh thanks for the link. Yes I think so, Jake's answer explains that `The bins parameter tells you the number of bins that your data will be divided into. ` but it doesn't seem to be the case in the plot I've uploaded. Is that an error then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the maximum not the fixed number of bins that you can set. From elsewhere in the documentation:

> "This value will be used in an algorithm that will decide the optimal bin size such that the histogram best visualizes the distribution of the data"

Comment: Hi Raspberry, thanks for your answer. Is this(https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Histogram2d.html) the documentation you were referring to?

Comment: yes, that's where I found it and I figured it also applies here, since the two libraries are closely related.